# UITouch on overlapping UIViews

Tags: ios, uiview, uitouch

I have two views each of which contain two subviews.

Hit detection is working fine as long as the two top views do not overlap.
Hence I can touch subview marked A in the left side of the image below.

However as soon as the top two views overlap, there is just no way that the A view receives touches as view 1 is "above" view 2 and "eats" the touch.

Both View 1 and View 2 detect touches, as they can be moved around, hence need to detect and react to touches "in between" subviews.

This means that my two "top views" detection should say: "Oh, wait a minute, maybe I am ovelapping some other view and should pass the event to it, and only start a drag/move around if and only if no other view is 'below me'".

How would I do that?
[image]

Edit:
Thanks jaydee3

This didn't work at first, resulting into an infinite recursion: each view deferring to its sibling, which in turn defers back to the initiating view:

```
- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView * hit =  [super hitTest:point withEvent:event] ;

    if (hit == self) {
        for (UIView * sibling in self.superview.subviews) {
            if (sibling != self) {
                CGPoint translated = [self convertPoint:point toView:sibling] ;
                UIView * other = [sibling hitTest:translated withEvent:event] ;
                if (other) {
                    return other ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return hit ;
}
```

So, I added a "marked set" to keep track of which view already had been visited, and it now all works :)

```
- (UIView *) hitTest: (CGPoint) point withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {

    static NSMutableSet * markedViews = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:4] ;

    UIView * hit =  [super hitTest:point withEvent:event] ;

    if (hit == nil) return nil ;

    if (hit == self) {
        for (UIView * sibling in hit.superview.subviews) {
            if (sibling != hit) {
                if ([markedViews containsObject:sibling]) {
                    continue ;
                }

                [markedViews addObject:sibling] ;
                CGPoint translated = [hit convertPoint:point toView:sibling] ;
                UIView * other = [sibling hitTest:translated withEvent:event] ;
                [markedViews removeObject:sibling] ;

                if (other) {
                    return other ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return hit ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom subclass for your view (that containts the other two subviews) and overwrite the `hitTest:` method for it. In that method, check if the hitTest view is one of the two subviews, else return `nil`. So all touches will be ignored on your surrounding view. Resulting in a touch on the view below, which can handle it itself.

//edit: (You get the hitTest view by calling `UIView* view = [super hitTest:withEvent:];`.)

//edit2: i thought more of smth like that: :)

```
- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView * hit =  [super hitTest:point withEvent:event] ;

    if (hit == self) {
        return nil;
    }

    return hit ;
}
```

;)

Comment: That wouldn't work because this would prevent the top views from handling any event at all. In my edited question I have provided the code that now does work. Thanks again.

Comment: aah i didn't knew you need touches on these views too. allright. you're welcome.